# Rerendering lightning:recordViewForm OR single component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component similar to:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="myevent" action="{!c.myRerender}" />

    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="MyObj__c" />
</aura:component>
```

How can I get my `<lightning:recordViewform> to reload? Using`e.force:refreshView` is not a viable answer as it reloads other things as well.

Comment: Did you try loading `lightning:recordViewForm ` with a separate component using `$A.createComponent` ?

Comment: Not a duplicate as this use case is different and not answered in that question.

Comment: @dphil, including + code and what you have tried will likely reduce the chances of your posts being marked as duplicates.

Comment: @codeyinthecloud I have not.  Maybe I'll try that next.

Comment: For those that closed this, that linked question/answer does NOT answer this question/cover this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the recordEditForm stores the object in the DOM it will not automatically update unless it is re-pulled from server.  To do this just set the recordId attribute of the recordEditForm to null and then back to the correct record Id and it will grab the updated version of the record

AURA

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
<aura:handler name="myevent" action="{!c.myRerender}" />
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="MyObj__c">
```

JS

```
myRerender : function(cmp, event, helper){
    var recId = cmp.get('v.recordId');
    cmp.set('v.recordId', null);
    cmp.set('v.recordId', recId);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this solution?  I had approached my co-workers with this exact same solution and they had said they already tried this and it did not work.

Comment: I have used the handler on the refreshView event before and I know that changing an aura:if statements boolean value refreshed that part of the DOM

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it myself and see if it works then.

Comment: There is also the renderer.js aspect of lightning components which may be the preferred method of re-rendering the DOM but I've never gotten that to work right.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm

Comment: I just finished implementing it and I do notice a barely visible collapse but the record never gets updated.

Comment: I've never worked with lightning:recordViewForm but maybe its possible that the record is stored in the DOM in a hidden attribute.  You could consider updating the recordId to null and then back to the specific object and that might cause it to repull the object from the server

Comment: Your next idea worked.  If you wanted to put it into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Excellent! I just updated the answer, glad it worked out

Comment: One thing to note, since I was using the standard 'hasRecordId', I saved that value to another attribute just in case: <aura:attribute type="String" name="rId" default="{!v.recordId}" />

Comment: good catch, I'll add it to the answer